# create a directory name using the data in a file

Tags: bash, shell, cat, mkdir

I am having date in one file called sms.txt as below:

```
10032020
```

I need to use this data in `sms.txt` and set to a variable(`old_data`) and create it as directory a directory name. I tried the below code :

```
#!/bin/bash
set old_data = $(cat sms.txt)
mkdir $old_data
```

I need to create the directory name as `10032020`. But the directory name is not getting printed!

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
xargs mkdir <sms.txt
```

---

See: `man xargs`

Comment: Can you tell me how to set the data in a file to set to a variable?

Comment: I suggest to use: `old_data=$(cat sms.txt); mkdir "$old_data"`